# Why multiplying an integer by a number gives wrong answers in C Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to calculate the value of the potentiometer equivalent to the angle, so I need to multiply by 180 and then divide by the range.
Upon doing so, I noticed that the number I'm getting is not the number I was expecting so I started debugging by multiplying by 180 only and realized the output was not as predicted.
**Here is the simple code that outputs the weird readings:**
`

```
#define POTENTIOMETER_PIN A0
int val;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(POTENTIOMETER_PIN);
  Serial.println(val*180);
  delay(250);
}
```

`

A value between (0 to 1023)*180 was expected, rather the serial monitor spits out values such as:
-18932
-18752
-18572
-18392
-18392

Comment: Integer overflow? The allowed values for an `int` can be as small as -32768 to 32767.

Comment: What is the range of your integers on Arduino? I would guess it is 16 bit only. You can only do `*32` then

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: I think both of those possible duplicates describe the problem, but not very clearly what to do about it; try using a larger type (than simply `int`  such as a _32-bit integer_) or reducing the precision you need (for example if you're resizing an output to display from millivolts to just volts) .. however, here specifically, you likely want the `map()` function!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `map()` function for your use case
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/

```cpp
int val = 0;  // assign at declaration

void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(POTENTIOMETER_PIN);  // read value
  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 180);      // convert into 180 range
  Serial.println(val);                  // display value
}
```

Internally, this makes use of a larger type than the humble `int`, using a `long`, which is (probably) 32-bits rather than 16

From the documentation above

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

---

The reason this works better for you and can do the math correctly is because a 16-bit number doesn't contain enough precision for the multiplication, while `map()` uses a 32-bit number internally to represent the value while it does the math on it!

Specifically, **if, during your logic you rely on 16-bit math, the value exceeds that ~32768 range, it will *wrap around* and become negative!**

This is known as [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which the Wikipedia article linked has a great demonstration of using a car odometer
the 100,000th mile is *overflowing* and wraps around to 1 because the first digit doesn't have room and so is truncted

[image: integer_overflow]

---

Some more labouring the point from the `int` docs on Arduino, specifically because while there is much debate (including *why* Arduino chooses to supply `int` at all) it's generally good practice to always specify exactly the type you you're after such as `uint32_t`, rather than relying on `int`, which frustratingly can have a different size on different device targets

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

> On the Arduino Uno (and other ATmega based boards) an int stores a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 (minimum value of -2^15 and a maximum value of (2^15) - 1).

> On the Arduino Due and SAMD based boards (like MKR1000 and Zero), an int stores a 32-bit (4-byte) value. This yields a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31) - 1).

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that your compiler defines int as being a 16 bit signed number.

Thus there is a limit of 32767 to -32768.

You are exceeding this and so the values 'wrap around'.

Try changing the code to use 'long' instead of 'int'.

Comment: Might be better to use `int32_t` or possibly `uint32_t` from `stdint.h` header, if it is available.

Comment: I am sure this was not asked for the first time on SO

Comment: @Dino Where'd you get those numbers?  2^15 = 32768 and therefore the largest postitive number is 32767 and the largest negative number is -32768

Comment: You are right, a messed up the calculation rushing. Thanks for pointing it out.